# "Более худшем" — грамотно ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, степени-прилагательных

*Грамотно ли говорить **"более худшем"**?* Эта фраза в новостях зачастую встречается. Почему же редакторы не исправляют?..

Comment: Например "Регионы РФ окажутся в более худшем положении".

Или, может, у авторов новостей другой стиль, а в обычной речи это недопустимо?

Answer (score 8):

Значит, такие редакторы и корректоры, сейчас и не такое встретишь. Это раньше речь дикторов и корреспондентов была эталоном, а сейчас зачастую - материал для пародистов. Вы правы, НЕЛЬЗЯ соединять формы превосходной и сравнительной степени, а также простые и составные формы обеих степеней сравнения! Например, НЕЛЬЗЯ *более худшее, самый тончайший, наименее красивее.* МОЖНО *более худой, худший* или *хуже, самый тонкий* или *тончайший, наименее красивый* или *красивее.* В данном случае - "в худшем положении".

Answer (score 6):

Согласна с ответом Людмилы, если говорить об общих правилах образования степеней сравнения. Но что касается конкретного примера (более худший) - не совсем. Еще Виноградов в своей книге "Русский язык. Грамматическое учение о слове" этой словоформе уделил отдельное внимание. (Не знаю точно год выпуска. Нашла, что 1986. Но я училась в 1980–1985 - и мы уже, помню, конспектировали эту работу.) Виноградов говорит о том, что слова младший и старший в современном русском языке потеряли значение превосходной степени. На мой взгляд, то же самое происходит и со словом худший.

*Цитата:*

Слова младший, старший совершенно утратили оттенки степеней сравнения. Они не соотносительны с младой (молодой) и старый. Ср., например: младший помощник надзирателя, старший хранитель, старший научный сотрудник, младший сын (если сыновей больше двух), старший сын, старший в команде, в старших классах, книги для детей старшего, среднего и младшего возраста и т. п. Но ср. у Герцена в "Былом и думах": "У моего отца был еще брат, старший обоих"; также у Пушкина в "Братьях-разбойниках": "Я старший был пятью годами" и т. п. Впрочем, при подчеркнутом сопоставлении и сравнении значение сравнительной степени, поддерживаемое формой старше, может и теперь выступить в словах старший, младший. Например, при наличии только двух сыновей в семье выражение старший (или младший) сын приобретает в определенной ситуации сравнительное значение (но при многих детях за старшим следует второй, третий и т. п., вплоть до младшего; при трех за старшим — средний, следовательно, в этих случаях старший и младший совсем теряют оттенок сравнительной степени).

Наконец, слова худший и лучший, совмещая все три значения форм на -ейш-, -айш-, легко сочетаются с усилительной формой самый, например: привет и самые лучшие пожелания; самое худшее, что только можно себе представить, и т. п. (101) По отношению к лучшему и худшему никакое усиление качества не кажется преувеличенным.

Кроме того, необходимо подчеркнуть отсутствие полного смыслового параллелизма между лучший и хороший — лучше; между худший и плохой — хуже (так же как и между большой, великий, больше и больший; между малый, маленький, меньше и меньший; между высокий — выше и высший; между низкий — ниже и низший)26 . Ср. лучший ударник; ср.: лучший из людей и хороший человек и т. п.

Подробнее [тут](http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5310&0a0=9).

Кроме этого автора, есть еще упоминание в учебниках по культуре речи. Если очень нужно, поищу чуть позже.

Answer (score 4):

Это ошибка. Смешение простой и составной формы сравнительной степени прилагательных.
 "худший" - это простая форма сравнительной степени  от "худой" в значении "плохой".

Answer (score 1):

Зачем торопиться и запрещать нормальное словоупотребление? Если повсеместно применяется сочетание "самый худший", то чем же вам не по нраву "более худший"??

"Нельзя исключить и **самого худшего варианта**, однако друзья все еще надеются, что он жив и просто старается спрятаться от длинной руки КГБ." (В.Аксенов) + тысяча других примеров.

"Обе они сегодня много говорят или же они обе просто нервничают, как нервничают женщины при всякой перемене, опасаясь, как водится, **чего-то еще более худшего.**" (Владимир Маканин)

"Я бы мог это сделать раньше да беда в том, что все окружающие меня богаты так же как и я, даже **находятся в еще более худшем положении** ибо почти все курят, а купить курева не на чего." (Александр Гнедин)

" ― **Чтобы обрести более худший,** ― добавил, смотря на меня в упор, Бехтерев." (А. Л. Чижевский)

А вот вам примеры самого наилучшего :

"Непостоянный во всех своих начинаниях, а тем более продолжениях, неустойчивый в настроении, Никита должен был ещё и поддерживать Насера, и снабжать ракетами Кастро, и изобретать окончательный (**уже самый наилучший) способ** спасения и полного расцвета сельского хозяйства, да где-то же и космос подогнать, и лагеря укрепить, ослабшие после падения Берии." (А. И. Солженицын. Бодался теленок с дубом)

"Штурманский сундук купи, **самый наилучший, со всем инструментом** навигаторским…" (Ю.П.Герман)

"Отменнейший скус, я вам доложу… **Самый наилучший** ― а ла ваниль… У вас его, кажись, не варят?" (Мельников-Печерский)

Русская литературная практика явно расходится с категорическими запретами справочных пособий на "неправильное" образование различных видов сравнительной и превосходной степеней! Тем более, что речь идет не об экзаменах, а о нормальном, обычном словоупотреблении.

"И этот патриотизм **едва ли не самый худший**, потому что самый озлобленный и требующий наибольшего насилия." (Л. Н. Толстой. Патриотизм или мир?)

Comment: Коллеги по форуму, ответьте : приведенные литературные цитаты неграмотны? Или писатели не обращают внимание на надоедливых нормировщиков языка.

Answer (score 1):

> Пожилые люди находились в еще более худшем положении, часто просто за гранью нищеты.
> В. В. Путин "Послание Федеральному собранию 2012 год"

Подобные конструкции конечно неграмотны, но становятся всё более и более употребительны.

Comment: От политика слышу!